# How to use backends on gae with automatic scaling

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am new in gwt java GAE. i want use backends in my app. i tried backend.xml but it did not work. And I am using automatic scaling.

My backend.xml is :-

```
<backends>
  <backend name="vijaydynamic">
  <class>B8</class>
   <instances>5</instances>
   <options>
     <dynamic>true</dynamic>
   </options>
  </backend>
</backends>
```

and how to check my app using backends.

Any help

Comment: btw, do you understand that "_The Backend API is deprecated as of March 13, 2014_"? If you're developing a new app it's better to use Modules instead

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by wanting to 'use backends' in your application.  As Igor commented, the Backends API is long since deprecated so you should look at the newer [Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) architecture.

Modules run as part of the same application / project but can have different scaling characteristics and even different runtimes.  This means you can partition your code so as to scale only what needs scaling.  As with the old backends, Modules share the same datastore, etc.

You could, for example, have a very lean *Automatic* scaling Go module for handling user-facing requests, but a Java *Basic* scaling module processing task queues or cron jobs.

The different scaling options are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) but if you want anything not manual, you will want to look at Automatic (the default) and Basic.

There's also a `ModulesService` which provides an API ([javadocs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/package-summary)) for working with modules.